# Dotfuscator from .NET 2.0

Tags: .net-2.0, dotfuscator

Is there any chance to see Application Runs on Codeplex with .NET 2.0 application? I explored Dotfuscator is using web service url *http://so-s.info/PreEmptive.Web.Services.Messaging/MessagingServiceV2.asmx*. Is possible to track application run event manually? Something like add web service reference and call:

```
Dotfuscator.MessageCache messages = new Dotfuscator.MessageCache();
messages.Business.CompanyId = new Guid("3E35F098-CE43-4F82-9E9D-05C8B1046A45");
messages.Application.Id = new Guid("my app guid");
messages.Application.Name = Application.ProductName;
messages.Application.Version = Application.ProductVersion;
Dotfuscator.MessagingServiceV2 s = new Dotfuscator.MessagingServiceV2();
s.Publish(messages);
```

Comment: Added an update to my answer for non-.NET 4 applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to instrumenting your .NET 2.0 application hosted on CodePlex you don't have to do that manually.  You can use the free version of Dotfuscator in Visual Studio 2010 to instrument application binaries compiled against .NET 2.0 and higher.

You can continue to build .NET 2.0 applications and use either the custom attribute library (PreEmptive.Attributes.dll) in any .NET 2.0 or higher solution, use the Dotfuscator GUI to define the injection points or any combination of the two and Dotfuscator will not change the runtime environment of your application.

The instrumentation engine will use appropriate injection for assemblies compiled under .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, Compact Framework 2.0 and higher, and Silverlight 2, 3 and 4.  If you use only the Dotfuscator user interface to define your injection points you don't even need the original source code as it only requires the application binaries.

Added May 11, 2010:

The version of the PreEmptive.Attributes.dll that ships in Visual Studio 2010 is targeted only at .NET 4 and higher applications.  To fully support non .NET 4.0 applications we have posted a version of the library at http://runtimeintelligence.codeplex.com/releases/ that can be used by .NET 2.0 and higher applications.  This library is also allowed to be redistributed with CodePlex hosted open source project source code.

Comment: When I'm referencing to PreEmptive.Attributes.dll from .NET 2.0 project in VS2010, it tells me I have to upgrade to higher version of .NET. But I want keep my project in .NET 2.0.

Comment: I will continue in this thread at Dotfuscator related forum: http://www.preemptive.com/forum/index.php?f=10&t=184&sid=8b2369bd9c24108909152d22fe996fdd&rb_v=viewtopic